# Can I send c2dm push messages to an android device in which the primary account is the role sender account

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I developed an app which  uses c2dm. It's implemented at 
http://www.controlyourandroid.appspot.com

It's working perfectly when I'm trying it in an emulator or in my friends device. But when I use my own android phone (HTC WildFire, and 2.2.1), I'm not receiving c2dm messages.

I don't know why?
The registration is successful and I'm getting a registration id in my device.
Is it because my primary account in my phone and the role sender account that I'm using for the app is the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I recall the answer is no. This may change as C2DM is still a beta project (as far as I know). We are using C2DM in one of our Android applications, and we ran into problems using the role sender account on a device. There may be a workaround, but we just created a dedicated gmail email address to use with the C2DM service.